# Inserting delete button for each table not working

Tags: mysql, pdo, html-table

I did try some solutions from the same problem with mine but nothings working. I bet it's totally in my code. I'm trying to place them in every table that has been looped, It worked I was able to get a button on every table but I can't get them to work. Here's my code

```
<?php

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=library_member', $username = 'root', $password = '');
$q = "SELECT * FROM user_list";
$stmt = $con->prepare($q);
$stmt -> execute();
?>

<table border="1">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Firstname</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td>Email</td>


<?php   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td><button><a href='library-delete.php?id=$id/'>Delete</a></button></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

And this is the code for where the deleting happens.

```
<?php

    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=library_member', $username = 'root', $password = '');
    $q = "DELETE FROM user_list WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bindParam( ':id' , $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
    $stmt->execute();

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Information have been deleted.');
            window.location='library-showlist.php';
            </script>"; 


?>
```

It would just directly send me on the prompt part. None of my input data is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code like this:

```
library-delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Check again please.

Comment: oh yeah. I intent to do it. But It says I need to wait a few minutes before I can accept as an answer so I guess I'll have to wait ;) thanks again.